# In Python, how to tweak Black formatter, if possible?

Tags: python, code-formatting

I know that Black is an opinionated formatter, but I love everything it does except one major thing. When I have a function with multiple arguments, instead of displaying it like this:

```
def example_function(arg_1: str, arg_2: bool, arg_3: int = 0, arg_4: int = 1, arg_5: float = 0.0):
    pass
```

I'd rather display it as follows for readability:

```
def example_function(
    arg_1: str, 
    arg_2: bool, 
    arg_3: int = 0, 
    arg_4: int = 1, 
    arg_5: float = 0.0
):
```

Is this achievable with Black or some other formatter? I have this problem several times and it makes me consider not to use Black, either something else or nothing at all.

Any ideas or comments?

Comment: Maybe `blue` supports this: https://blue.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is due to the default line length for `black` being longer than you'd like – *88 characters per line*.

To decrease the line length, you can use the `--line-length` flag as documented here:

https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html

For example:

```bash
$ black --line-length 80 example.py
```

Black explains the `--line-length` setting in more detail here:

https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#line-length

> ### Line length
>
> You probably noticed the peculiar default line length. *Black* defaults
> to 88 characters per line, which happens to be 10% over 80. This
> number was found to produce significantly shorter files than sticking
> with 80 (the most popular), or even 79 (used by the standard library).
> In general, [90-ish seems like the wise choice](https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M?t=260).
>
> If you're paid by the line of code you write, you can pass
> `--line-length` with a lower number. *Black* will try to respect that. However, sometimes it won't be able to without breaking other rules.
> In those rare cases, auto-formatted code will exceed your allotted
> limit.
>
> **You can also increase it, but remember that people with sight
> disabilities find it harder to work with line lengths exceeding 100
> characters. It also adversely affects side-by-side diff review on
> typical screen resolutions. Long lines also make it harder to present
> code neatly in documentation or talk slides.**

*Emphasis on the final paragraph.*

I'd recommend just keeping the default settings. The beauty of *Black* is that it chooses for you, and therefor preempts any arguments about which way is *"best"*.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up decreasing it to 60 since I usually work on VScode with split windows, that fits nicely. Great answer! I also enjoyed the video about the 90ish, good watch. +1

Comment: There is a alias named `-l`

Comment: The other problem with changing the line length falls on the `next guy` running Black. He has to know what `you` chose or many many lines will be modified.

Comment: @sqqqrly You can just set your preferred line length in pyproject.toml.

Comment: Isn't PEP8's recommended value 79?

Comment: @RTD they talk about that in the quoted text "or even 79 (used by the standard library)…" The reasoning behind 79 characters is based on having side-by-side editors, on monitors without modern screen resolutions. Today, you can fit a lot more characters on a single line comfortably, and 88 chars avoids having to awkwardly split lines that run a few characters longer without being too long to follow.

Comment: The great thing about standards is there's so many to choose from.

Answer (score 58):

This is now possible by adding a trailing comma to your last argument.

In your example you would write instead:

```py
def example_function(
    arg_1: str, 
    arg_2: bool, 
    arg_3: int = 0, 
    arg_4: int = 1, 
    arg_5: float = 0.0, # <-- Notice the trailing comma
):
```

Comment: Too bad there is not an option to add this extra comma every time and have the 1 argument/line as well instead of tweaking the line length
Prettier handles that way better for NodeJs TS env and I think black could be inspired from this tool

Comment: Nice, thats exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

When using the Black playground at https://black.now.sh, I found that your function was reformatted exactly like that [when the line length was short enough](https://black.now.sh/?version=stable&state=_Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L-Wj4ACsAHpdAD2IimZxl1N_WlbvK5V89Lw1SkhVsxzpwoqUVQEsqaofOdMHvIBUkcGW2US-dpPwfqjCRV2ao43Df05ntzMjt65qs0j49I0tzQ7t4FGxf-ZZ0_LfI2D-I7XVtvUwLoqeNuc6TJ_JYQMdTKy_lmPjpGPocQ05UXkdP08AAAAAz0nSwE3c0JAAAZYBrQEAANyjyYuxxGf7AgAAAAAEWVo=) (in particular, at 78 characters).

It might be nice if there were a special configuration option that controlled the line length specifically for function parameter lines.  BUT to seems to me that Black's configuration-free approach means that there is no way to control this with any more tailored option.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I tried black.now.sh a bit, worth it! I appreciate your answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

For those using visual studio code (add two lines one for `--line-length` other for the length: `119`):

[image]